# Does findAllBy return a sorted list?

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

Does findAllBy return a sorted list? I could not find any information in the Grails documentation about this. Assuming I have a class like so:

```
class Something {

  int sortOrder
  String label

  static belongsTo = [ somethingElse: SomethingElse]
  static mappedBy = [somethingElse: SomethingElse]

  static mapping = {
    tablePerHierarchy false
    sort "sortOrder"
  }

  static constraints = {
  }
}
```

Does Something.findAllBySomethingElse(somethingElse) return a list that is sorted by "sortOrder"? It's strange but my unit tests says no whereas my grails app (when i do run-app) displays the list in sorted order. I had to explicitly use findAllBySomethingElse(somethingElse, [sort: "sortOrder"]) to enable my unit tests (i.e. checking sort order) to pass.

Comment: You can also have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3659935

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does return a sorted list. But not in Unit Tests. They are not intended for such things, but can be extended to some degree. See the [unit test documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/guide/testing.html#unitTestingDomains).

Comment: Thanks. But how do I pass my unit tests, which depends on the sort order without changing my production code? A simple unit test written to test the sort order of findAllBy will always fail. Which also means that any code dependent on the sort order of findAllBy will also fail its unit tests.

Comment: I recommend to test this kind of functionality in integration tests, not unit tests.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about it and I guess I could refactor out my code and fake the results of findAllBy which might make a better design. Thanks :)

Comment: Its been a while but I realised that when you define a relationship in grails (see http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#sets,ListsAndMaps), you get a java.util.set. Which is unordered. Therefore, it seems my unit test was failing correctly after all.